# how to refresh fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity where on the last fragment there is a button to send the user to `ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS`. Then when the user presses the back button, it's still my last fragment. I make the `INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE` appear, but when something is selected on that dialog, I want to reload my activity. I know how to reload the activity but I don't know how I can detect when something is selected on the `INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE`.

This is the way I read my activity in onResume:

```
Globals.securityWizardPage = 4;
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecurityWizardActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);        
getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: Some pointer for you if you call startActivityForResults() you may get the results but not sure that's why not giving it as answer.

Comment: Another point when you call `ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS` sometimes there may not be an activity which can handle this type of intent so make sure you are handling that case.

Comment: i'm handling this with a variable, i found the solution launching the fragment after a few seconds, its not the best way but works for what i want